# Items in an SQL table with PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an SQL table for a gallery, it has rows for id, userid, imagename.
I'm trying to write a function that calculates how many images a certain user has added, I'm new to PDO and SQL. This is what I have for my function;

```
// Photo Count
public function photoCount($id){
  $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id = :id');
  // Bind value
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

  $row = $this->db->single();

  // Check row
  $count = $this->db->rowCount();

  return $count;  
}
```

Do I need the line `$row = $this->db->single();` or can I just return the `rowCount` at the moment all is being returned is 0's which is incorrect.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL count function. If `$this->db` is a PDO object then...

```
public function photoCount($id){
  $statement = $this->db->prepare('SELECT count(*) as c FROM gallery WHERE id = :id');
  $statement->bindParam(":id", $id);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  return $result->c;
}
```

Comment: You can use something like [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to make this even more concise